# Spring boot service pass java option

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have spring-boot application running as a init service through the executable jar. Going through the documentation I wanted pass JAVA_OPTS for heap size to the executable jar.

Currently, the following config is being used

```
 <embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
    <inlinedConfScript>JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx8000m -Xms8000m</inlinedConfScript>
 </embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
```

I am not sure it works as through jmap maxHeapSize is around 2000mb (2gb)

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: I have the same requirement and I've tried out `inlinedConfScript` in the version 2.0.0.M7 , what I found is that `inlinedConfScript` expects a file path ,not the actual script.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48762587/1500274)'s the example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly add these configurations while running your JAR file?
For example:

```
java -Xmx8000m -Xms8000m -jar xxx.jar
```

Comment: will it work as an executable script like spring boot mention in docs or should I apply some other steps?